# Django and Flask on same nginx server

Tags: python, nginx, flask

I currently have a Djago app running on my main site when I visit mysite.com. However, I'd like mysite.com/flaskapp to run a separate Flask application. I'm able to set up two nginx site-enabled config files and run each app on a different port but, for various reasons, I'd like to run them all on the same port (if possible). When I configure my flaskapp/ location in my nginx server file I get a 404 error.

Here's my supervisor config file:

```
[program:MYSITE]
command=/var/www/html/MYSITE/prodenv/bin/gunicorn --workers 3 --bind unix:/var/www/html/MYSITE/public_html/MYSITE.sock MYSITE.wsgi
directory=/var/www/html/MYSITE/public_html
autostart=true
autorestart=true
stderr_logfile=/var/log/MYSITE.err.log
stdout_logfile=/var/log/MYSITE.out.log


[program:FLASKAPP]
directory=/var/www/html/MYSITE/public_html/FLASKAPP/api
command=/var/www/html/MYSITE/public_html/FLASKAPP/venv/bin/gunicorn --workers 3 --bind unix:/var/www/html/MYSITE/public_html/FLASKAPP/api/FLASKAPP.sock FLASKAPP:app
autostart=true
autorestart=true
stderr_logfile=/var/log/FLASKAPP.err.log
stdout_logfile=/var/log/FLASKAPP.out.log
```

And my nginx site-enabled file:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    listen [::]:80;

    server_name MYSITE;

    location = /favicon.ico { access_log off; log_not_found off; }

    location /static/ {
        root /var/www/html/MYSITE/public_html;
        expires 30d;
    }

    location / {
        include proxy_params;
        proxy_pass http://unix:/var/www/html/MYSITE/public_html/MYSITE.sock;
    }

    location /FLASKAPP/ {
        include proxy_params;
        proxy_pass http://unix:/var/www/html/MYSITE/public_html/FLASKAPP/api/FLASKAPP.sock; 
    }
}
```

I wrote a function to check the request url

```
    @app.errorhandler(404)
    def page_not_found(error):
         return 'This route does not exist {}'.format(request.url), 404
```

Which returns:

This route does not exist http://MYSITE/FLASKAPP

The Flask app is clearly working, but the routing is screwed up. How can I fix this?

Comment: Have you checked your nginx log?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I figured it out. I rewrote the url to remove the subdirectory and now it all works:

```
      rewrite ^/FLASKAPP(.*)$ $1 break;
```

Comment: Care to explain where did you apply this? A before and after edit of the edited configuration file would be more helpful than a vague answer.

Comment: I found this is related to Nginx configuration file. Did you the rewrite directive inside or outside the location block? Also, it would be nice to know what made you come with the solution. Thanks!

Comment: @BringBackCommodore64 I added this line inside the location block of my site-enabled nginx config file. That line was the only addition I made to the location block and I found it by echoing the urls and routes in  my app.